# How I can install a Brother DCP-J715W

Tags: drivers

The system settings see it under network printer, but there is no such model on the database list, and when I go to "search for a printer driver to downlaod", it says there is "no matches found".

Where can I get the appropriate driver?

Answer (score 0):

You can download it from here [Brother drivers for Linux](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/download_prn.html#DCP-J715W)

After you download the .deb file, you can install it by giving the command
**sudo dpkg -i "package name".deb**